# How can I tell whether my data is skewed due to sampling error?

Tags: sampling, skewness

I have some psychological data (N=100, 2 conditions) in which across 55 questions participants made an estimate, and then after a manipulation they made an additional estimate. I then calculated how much their estimate gained or lost on the second round. There were two manipulations that occurred before the second round, and each participant received one of them.

I found that in both conditions estimates (on average) improved in the second round compared to the first. However, the median 'improvement' from round 1 to round 2 was negative. This was true across both conditions.

It's been suggested to me that the reason for this was just sampling error. Is there a way for me to investigate the plausibility of this suggestion without re-doing my study?

In response to Erik's question, here is a link to the raw data: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/53771404/estimation_data.xlsx.

Column 1 = Mean error of original estimates.
Column 2 = Mean error of second estimates.
Column 3 = Median error of original estimates.
Column 4 = Median error of second estimates.

This is just manipulation condition 1, but the second condition had very similar results.

Comment: You are going to have to explain what "estimates ... improved" and "change ... was negative" mean.  Otherwise it could be for example that the initial estimates were too high and then they reduced and got better.

Comment: OK, I altered median change and made it median 'improvement'. The point was on average the Round 1 estimates were better, but on median the Round 2 estimates were better.

Comment: So how did you test whether the estimates improved? Paired t-test? It seems to boil down to the mean change being positive and the median change being negative... Can you go into detail how you set up your analysis? Did you control for the baseline (first round) in addition to looking at the differences?

Comment: I just looked at the means initially, and having done some paired t-tests now they returns a sig value of about .2 for all comparisons. I've attempted to provide some more detail by providing a link to the data above. Could you please explain more about what you mean by controlling for the baseline?